# Pass data between view controllers WITHOUT segues

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller

I'm using storyboard and I have a view that loads dynamic buttons. On click of this button, I need to load the second view controller and also pass data. I cannot use segue as its dynamic button.

I use following code to load the second view controller

```
UIStoryboard*  sb1 = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard_iPhone"
                                                           bundle:nil];
UIViewController* vc1 = [sb1 instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SecondViewController"];


[self.navigationController pushViewController:vc1 animated:YES];
```

In the 2nd view controller, I need to access about 5 fields from the 1st view controller. How do I pass the data?

Comment: Why dont you just set the information you need on the new viewcontroller before pushing it? you already have your instance of the VC. Make the properties public (declared in the header) or create new ones to fill your data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a Segue not bounded to a button by ctrl+drag from the first controller to the second one (don't forget to give this segue and identifier).

Next In the IBAction of the button (set via Interface Builder or via `addTarget:self action:forControlEvents:` ) you can call the `[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"YourSegueIdentifier" sender:button];`

You can pass the data to the second controller, as usual, in `- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender`

Answer (score 1):

Try something like that:

Class A

```
// CLASS_A.h
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface CLASS_A : UIViewController {
    ...
}
- (IBAction)Btn_PushPressed:(id)sender;
...
@end

// CLASS_A.m
#import "CLASS_A.h"
#import "CLASS_B.h"
@implementation CLASS_A

- (IBAction)Btn_PushPressed:(id)sender
{
    UIStoryboard*  sb1 = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard_iPhone"
                                                       bundle:nil];
    CLASS_B* vc1 = [sb1 instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SecondViewController"];
    vc1.delegate = self;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:vc1 animated:TRUE];
}

....
@end
```

Class B

```
// CLASS_B.h
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@class CLASS_A;
@interface CLASS_B : UIViewController {
    ...
}
@property (weak, nonatomic) CLASS_A *delegate;
....
@end

// CLASS_B.m
#import "CLASS_B.h"
#import "CLASS_A.h"
@implementation CLASS_B
....
@end
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how to do it in Swift 2.0. Instead of using `prepareForSegue`,

> **Swift 3.0**

```
let someViewConroller = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SomeViewController") as! SomeViewController
someViewConroller.someObject = self.someObject!
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(someViewConroller, animated: true)
```

> **Swift 2.0**

```
let someViewConroller = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("SomeViewController") as! SomeViewController
someViewConroller.someObject = self.someObject!
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(someViewConroller, animated: true)
```

Comment: How about swift 3 ?

Comment: Will add Swift 3.0 @Maven ;)

Comment: Here you go @Maven

Comment: "someObject" is shown as not a member of someViewController.
I am not exactly using your code.
`var someViewController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "listView") as! ListVC`. This the code I am using. Any issues ?

Comment: @Maven someObject is just an example to show you how you can pass objects between `ViewController` without segues. Which object are you looking to pass? Just replace that with `someObject`

Answer (score 1):

Swift 3

```
let destinationView = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ID") as! ViewController2
destinationView.Value2 = Value1
self.present(destinationView, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use

> NSUserDefaults

to store the data and retrieve in what ever page you need

In view controller A

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:aData forKey:@"DATA"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

In destination Controller

```
NSData * aData = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"DATA"];
```

Answer (score 0):

firstly you can use segue even you have dynamic buttons, just add target method to UIButtons and push view controller using segue in that method. in the second view controller, take few properties and assign values to those properties before you push second view controller. like:

```
UIStoryboard*  sb1 = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard_iPhone"
                                               bundle:nil];
UIViewController* vc2 = [sb1 instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SecondViewController"];

[vc2 setName:@"name"];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:vc2 animated:YES];
```

before that you need to assign property to a NSString *name in SecondViewController

Comment: i have added more comments please check

Answer (score 0):

You can define a protocol: PassValueDelegate,and in the first viewController you can implement this protocol.

```
UIStoryboard*  sb1 = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard_iPhone" bundle:nil];
UIViewController* vc1 = [sb1 instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SecondViewController"];
//set the delegate for the second view controller,so you can access the values in the first controller
vc1.delegate = self;
[self.navigationController pushViewController:vc1 animated:YES];
```